# Principal argument in rest controller method

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, authorization

How can i use `Principal` object as argument in controller method instead use `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal()`

I use spring 4, spring mvc

My Rest Controller

```
@RestController
@Api(value = "Dictionary Resource")
@RequestMapping("/test")
public class TestControllerImpl {
    @RequestMapping(value = "test", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, consumes = MediaType.ALL_VALUE)
        public TestDTO test(Principal principal) {
        System.out.println("principal = "+principal.getName()); // this is null pointner exception, principal is null, but i want this use

        Principal principal1 = (Principal)SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
        System.out.println("principal1() = "+principal1.getName()); // this work fine
    }
}
```

I Have class HandlerInterceptor as below:

```
@Component
public class MyHandlerInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {


    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
         MyAuthentication auth= MyAuthentication.builder().login("admin").build();
         SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth);
         return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterCompletion(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, Exception ex) throws Exception {

    }
}
```

And Authentication class with Principal

```
@Data
@Builder
public class MyAuthentication implements Authentication{

    private String login;

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>(1);
        authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"));
        return authorities;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getCredentials() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getDetails() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getPrincipal() {
        return (Principal)() -> login;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAuthenticated() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void setAuthenticated(boolean isAuthenticated) throws IllegalArgumentException {

    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return login;
    }

    public static Principal getCurrentPrincipal(){
        return (Principal) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried annotating parameter in controller method with @AuthenticationPrincipal?

Comment: @ago  Principal with `@AuthenticationPrincipal` also not work

Comment: @skwisgaar not work

Comment: strange, out of curiosity I forked some sample spring security project and added `@AuthenticationPrincipal` to controller, it works as expected (you can check the last commit at https://github.com/loonydevil/example-spring-boot-security). am I right that you're getting autopopulated principal as null but at the same time security context holder returns it correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Principal arguent in rest controller works as expected in this example.

```
@RestController
public class MyController {

    @GetMapping("/greeting")
    public Greeting greeting(Principal principal, @RequestParam(value = "name", defaultValue = "World") String name) {... }
```